# Any ideas on how to link members to entries?

Tags: channel-entries, members

I'm planning a new site that will have a list of entries and a database of members (nothing unusual there I hear you say).

What I'm trying to work out is how to allow a member to express interest in one or more entries?

**The scenario would be something like this...**

- The member would log in
- They would then browse or search entries
- When they find one they like the could click a button to express interest in that entries
- They could then do the same for other entries if they choose
- Another member could then log in, browse entries and see which other members are interested in that entry

All thoughts will be gratefully received!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [LikEE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/likee), [Like](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/like), [Favorites](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/favorites) or [Shortlist](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortlist) would fit the bill?

Comment: @Tyssen - any particular favorites?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used any of them, just what a quick search on Devotee threw up.